# MS SQL CE DataContext Database exist/delete

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce

I used SQLite before but I wasn't able to create a database using a `DataContext` (AFAIK the SQLite does not support it) so I switched to MS SQL CE 4 (which I know is deprecated but it can still be xcopy-installed and relatively small) but I have problem with the database creation.

First, I've tried without opening a connection but the `DatabaseExists` returned false. I thought that I must open a connection, so now I'm trying to use the `DataContext`'s `DatabaseExists` and `DeleteDatabase` with an opened connection. I'm creating a connection like this:

```
SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder();
stringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;

connection = new SqlCeConnection(stringBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

where the `dataSouce` is a relative name of the database.

Then I'm trying to use a strongly-typed `DataContext` (called `Context`) to determine if a database exsits and create if it doesn't.

```
protected DBDataProvider(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
{
    connection = connectionProvider.Connection;
    dataContext = new Context(connection);
}

public bool CreateDatabase(bool overwriteIfExists = true)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        if (dataContext.DatabaseExists())
        {
            if (overwriteIfExists)
                dataContext.DeleteDatabase();
            else
                return false;
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // in this case the database does not exist
        // at least with MS SQL CE
    }

    try
    {
        dataContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return true;
}
```

But the `DatabaseExists` always returns false. So I thought that must be an issue so I moved the `DeleteDatabase` call after closing the connection but nothing happens, the file is still there.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    // removed from here...
    connection.Close();

    dataContext.DeleteDatabase();
}
```

And because the database file is still there the `CreateDatabase` throws an exception:

`{System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): File already exists. Try using a different database name. [ File name = TestDB.db ] at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.CreateDatabase()`

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Edit**

Created a mini test-code and I was able to reproduce this issue.

- First run: no problem, the database file is created.
- Second run: exception because according to the data context object, the database does not exist

Here is the code:

```
public static class Test
{
    [Table(Name="test_table")]
    public class TestEntity
    {
        [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
        public Int32 Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Column(Name = "name", CanBeNull = false, DbType = "NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE")]
        public String Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [Database(Name = "TestDB")]
    public class TestContext : DataContext
    {
        public Table<TestEntity> Entities
        {
            get { return base.GetTable<TestEntity>(); }
        }

        public TestContext(IDbConnection connection)
            : base(connection)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void TryCreate(string dataSource)
    {
        IDbConnection connection;
        TestContext context;

        // create connection
        {
            SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;

            connection = new SqlCeConnection(stringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        }

        // create context
        context = new TestContext(connection);

        // create database
        if (context.DatabaseExists())
            context.DeleteDatabase();
        context.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Problem solved with using the proper (sdf) file extension.

Comment: Have you tried with a full path to the database file?

Comment: Just tried it, same results. Can it be some kind of permission issue?

Comment: How do you call your CreateDatabase code? Would be níce with some simpler repor code? It should be possible to use simple code like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399420(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Edited my post, added some repro code. First run: success, the database is created. Second run: the abova exception. I've put a breakpoint on the `DatabaseExists()` line but its value wasn't true.

Comment: Oh, I've found the problem: so I can't use any file extension. With MS SQL CE I *have to* use .sdf. If the filename is "MyTestDB.sdf" the above example works.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej)'s comments I've found the problem: the file extension.

It seems with MS SQL CE I *have to* use the **.sdf** file extension.